# How to manually convert point features to SVG coordinates

Tags: svg, d3.js, geo, map-projections

I have set up a `d3.geo.path` as follows

```
// Projection
var projection = d3.geo.mercator().center([LONCENTER, LATCENTER]).scale(MAPSCALE);
// Path for projection
path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

My task involves plotting pie charts on a world map, and I am using `path.centroid()` to place them  for most countries, but countries such as USA and Russia which are widespread do not render good results (e.g. the pie of USA being in Canada), thus I want to manually set centroids for these. This is the code I have so far:

```
function getCentroid(country){
if(id === 840){
    return path({ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-97, 40] });
// Russia
} else if(id === 643){
    return path({ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [49, 60] });
// France   
} else if(id === 250){
    return path({ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [3, 47] });
}
// default case where the standard centroid can be used
} else {
    return path.centroid(country.datum().geometry);
}
}
```

The problem is that this function returns something like `[487.25078795735465, 377.785536430209]` for the default case (which can be directly embedded into the `transform` attribute of an SVG element) but something like `"M209.12490009048008,338.6477191773128m0,4.5a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,-9a4.5,4.5 0 1,1 0,9z"` for the above special cases. What can I do in order to get simple x- and y-coordinates in these cases? I assume I could use RegEx but isn't there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass the custom points to the projection instead of the path, i.e.

```
return projection([-97, 40]);
```